# Django - How do I delete single database entries on button click?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to set up a user profile where you can enter skills. Entering the skills and save them in the databse already works. Now I want to give the user the opportunity to delete every single one of them with a button click. I tried posting the ID of each skill on button click in the URL and read it out in my view to get the item and delete it, but that does not work like I thought and I cant find out why...

**MY VIEW**

```
def profile_settings(request, id=None):
# get logged in user object from session
user_id = request.user.id
# get related userprofile
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
# get all skills of the userprofile
user_skills = Skill.objects.filter(user=userprofile)

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = SkillForm(request.POST)

    if 'delete-skill' in request.POST:
            if id:
                print(id)
                skill = Skill.objects.get(pk=id).delete()

    elif 'add-skill' in request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            # get data from form
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
            # create new skill object for a user
            new_skill = Skill(name=name, category=category, rating=rating, user=userprofile)
            # save it in the database
            new_skill.save()

else:
    form = SkillForm()
return render(request, 'profile-settings.html', {'skillform': form, 'existing_skills': user_skills})
```

**MY URLS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^landing', views.landing, name='landing'),
    url(r'^neuigkeiten', views.news, name='news'),
    url(r'^profileinstellungen/', views.profile_settings, name='profileinstellungen'),
    url(r'^profileinstellungen/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.profile_settings, name='profileinstellungen'),
]
```

**MY TEMPLATE**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" style="margin-top: 300px">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ skillform }}

        <input type="submit" value="Hinzufügen" name="add-skill "/>

    </form>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {% for skill in existing_skills %}
                <li>{{ skill.name }}</li>
                <input href="{% url 'profileinstellungen' id=skill.id%}" type="submit" value="Löschen" name="delete-skill"/>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

It does not post the ID of the skill in the URL. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Are you getting any specific error.?

Comment: Well when I click on the delete button the ID of the skill is not passed in the url so nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to include dollar signs at the end of the regexes in your URL patterns. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^landing$', views.landing, name='landing'),
    url(r'^neuigkeiten$', views.news, name='news'),
    url(r'^profileinstellungen/$', views.profile_settings, name='profileinstellungen'),
    url(r'^profileinstellungen/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.profile_settings, name='profileinstellungen'),
]
```

In particular, the problem is the regex `r'^profileinstellungen/`. Without the dollar, it matches URLs like  `/profileinstellungen/4/`, so the id is not passed to the view.

Secondly, it doesn't make sense to give the input an href attribute. Each input should be in a separate form, and you can set the form action to the URL you wish to submit the post request to.

```
<ul>
  {% for skill in existing_skills %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'profileinstellungen' id=skill.id%}">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <li>
         {{ skill.name }}
         <input type="submit" value="Löschen" name="delete-skill"/>
       </li>
    </form>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You haven't explained exactly what your problem is. My guess is that the URL tag is working, but the wrong URL pattern is matching the URL. If that's the case, then my answer *will* solve your problem.

Comment: My problem is following: When I click on a delete button of a certain skill, the id of that skill is not passed to the URL and nothing happens.

Comment: @Alasdair is right. Because you are not getting any error as such, it is probably matching to another URL. Else you would have faced a Reverse URL error or something like that.

Comment: Okay but I don't see where my mistake. I've changed my URL confs like Alasdair said, but the ID does not appear in the URL anyways :(

Comment: You are using POST method to submit your form.
If you want to send the ID in the URL then you need to change your METHOD from POST to GET. 
GET is used for sending parameters in the URL.

Comment: Can't believe I've overseen that, thank you. But it still won't work. If I now click a delete button the URL looks like that: /profileinstellungen/?delete-skill=Löschen whereas I would expect it to look like /profileinstellungen/2 (or any number)

Comment: Your other problem is that setting the href for the input doesn't make sense. You should set the form's action instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: @KyluAce the comments aren't the correct place to ask for help, that sounds like a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
<input href="{% url 'profileinstellungen' id=skill.id%}" type="submit" value="Löschen" name="delete-skill"/>
```

by this :

```
<input href="{% url 'profileinstellungen' %}{{skill.id}}" type="submit" value="Löschen" name="delete-skill"/>
```

because the "url" will know automatically that "skill.id" was related to "id"